# How to get OpenGL support on VirtualBox 5.2.8?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, opengl

I am trying to run a program, but I am struggling with getting getting the program to run because it requires OpenGL 2.0, and I have OpenGL 1.1.0. Is there any fix to this problem? I have updated windows and there is still no change.

This is the error I get:

> Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize 8, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapinterval 1., profile 0) . 
> This is most likely caused by not having the necessary graphics drivers installed. 
> Install a driver providing OpenGL 2.0 or higher, or, if this is not possible, make sure the ANGLE Open GL ES 2.0 emulation libraries (libEGL.dll, IibGLESv2.dll and d3dcompiler_*.d11) are available in the application executable's directory or in a location listed in PATH. 
>
> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your only solution would probably be upgrading to _OpenGL 2.0_.

Comment: @zx485, Well in my case, OpenGL is not upgradeable just like THAT. I need to update the drivers to SUPPORT OpenGL 2.0.VirtualBox, however, does not have those drivers. I need an answer for how I can solve my problem.

Comment: [Use a version of VirtualBox before OpenGL 2.0 support was disabled.](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=82614) or a different hypervisor entirely.  Unless you implement the patch yourself what you want isn’t possible with any recent version of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ran into the same issue and found that OpenGL 2.0 and higher is a bit broken in VirtualBox 5.x and, as far as I know, still not fully fixed.
With the GuestOS being Win7 or earlier it can be made to work by installing the guest drivers in safe-mode. For Windows 8 and later it will not work whatsoever.
There is an extensive thread on the matter on the [VirtualBox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=82614). (If the link should become broken Google for "Virtualbox opengl 2". Should be one of the first hits.)
With that info and some experimentation I was able to get OpenGl (2 and 3) working in a Windows 7 guest. (I can't recall exact details. It was over a year ago that I last played with this. But that forum-thread should give you all you need.)

I don't know if the problem has been solved with the current VirtualBox 6.x series. I haven't had an opportunity to try that yet.

Comment: I do indeed have windows 7 installed as my guest, and I tried installing my drivers in safe mode. This however, still did not work. I also have looked at that thread before, however it did not solve my problem. Can you help me with the error described in the image link that I posted above?

Comment: I will try updating Virtualbox to see if the problem is fixed

Comment: I can also try downgrading if you would tell me on what version you got it to work.

Comment: Virtualbox 6.0 did not fix the issue